# View only Rights in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

My client has given me readonly rights to bigquery data. BigQuery is asking to register for their service. Do I need to be a paid user to access the data

In simple words, how to access their data?
[image]

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Your client needs to execute this query to give you  permission to the dataset.

```
GRANT `roles/bigquery.metadataViewer`
ON schema `project_name.dataset_name`
TO "user:mail@mail.com"
```

After this query. You need to add  the project in BigQuery.

- Above the option +Add
- Pin a Project
- Enter Project Name

[image]

Comment: @user1693821 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.